# Encapsulate method without parameters and with return value

Tags: .net, function, function-pointers, encapsulation

I'm looking for something like Action<T> (*"Encapsulates a method that has a single parameter and does not return a value"*) and like Func<T, TResult> (*"Encapsulates a method that has one parameter and returns a value of the type specified by the TResult parameter"*), but I have to encapsulate a method without parameter and with return value.
Is there anything, or I have to write one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you want [`Func<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Func is capable of doing that. There are several variants of it, depending on the number of input parameters you're after, including none. It always takes a return type, though, e.g. `Func<int>` represents a function with no arguments, returning an int.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! There was no link to it in the MSDN, and i did't know Func<x,...>